# How can I re-design my old .rdlc reports in VS 2012 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, visual-studio-2012, rdlc, designer

I have many reports which I designed in VS 2010 Pro, now I only have **VS 2012 Express**, when I open the report it only opens as an **XML file**. I have been looking for solutions for ages without any success.

- How can I view the designer (I tried installing Sql Server 2008
  Express /w Advance Services) ?
- Are there any external designers that can see the custom Data Types?
  (I have tried fyiReporting)
- If both of the above are not possible, then is there anywhere I can
  find out how to edit the file by hand?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your reports were designed in VS 2010 that implies they are in SQL Server 2012 format.  I would try SQL Server 2012 Express.  It includes Report Designer via the Express edition of Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS).

The RDL specification is also available on MSDN if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Report Builder according to your SQL Server version

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Report Builder 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24085)

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP4 Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56043)

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42301)

[Microsoft® Report Builder SQL Version >= 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613)

**NOTE:** I downloaded 2008 version and when you open a file with the Report Builder the extension says `.rdl`, if you have `.rdlc` just choose `All Items (*.*)`

Also you don't need to have SQL Server installed to create/modify a report but if you want to test it you have to install it

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-rdl/4299384a-e826-4f69-bb06-f56d37155197) are the schema definitions for the RDL format according the SQL Server version